# Setting two labels in moderntimeline

Tags: moderncv, moderntimeline

I currently use `moderncv` and `moderntimeline` to create my curriculum vitae. While I'm very pleased with the outcome so far, I have not managed yet to specify a month in a `\tlcventry`.

A working minimal example looks like this

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\moderncvstyle{classic} % CV theme - options include: 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{orange} % CV color - options include: 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'

\usepackage[firstyear=2010,lastyear=2020]{moderntimeline}

\firstname{John} % Your first name
\familyname{Doe} % Your last name
\tlenablemonths

\begin{document}
\section{Tex Exchange}
\tlenablemonths
\tlcventry{2012/1}{2015/10}{entry}{entry}{entry}{entry}{entry}
\end{document}
```

I want the upper label of this entry to be 01/2012 and the lower label to be 10/2015. How can I achieve that?

Best regards and thank you in advance

Comment: You "need" to add a complete and minimal example of code in order to get people to help you here. Just look at most of the other questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in the preamble.

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\tl@formatstartyear}[1]{
  \startyeartrue
  \tl@yearfraction{#1}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\tl@startfraction{(\tl@startyear-\tl@firstyear)/(\tl@lastyear-\tl@firstyear)}%
  \ifissince
    \xdef\tl@startlabel{\tl@since \tl@tmpmonth/\tl@tmpyear}
  \else
    \xdef\tl@startlabel{\tl@tmpmonth/\tl@tmpyear}
  \fi
}
\renewcommand{\tl@formatendyear}[1]{
  \startyearfalse%
  \tl@yearfraction{#1}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\tl@endfraction{(\tl@endyear-\tl@firstyear)/(\tl@lastyear-\tl@firstyear)}%
  \ifissince%
    \xdef\tl@endlabel{}
  \else
    \xdef\tl@endlabel{\tl@tmpmonth/\tl@tmpyear}
  \fi
}
\makeatother
```